# vb.net web localhost statistic system

Tags: excel, statistics, system

I have loads of excel files with huge amount of numbers and graphs and formulas. What I would like to do is to store everything in database. It could be oracle, ms sql or my sql. Main goal is to have all excels in one place and create graphs, tables, comparison and so on, in one place. Is there online some product/software (free or not) for this kind of system? I could edit it, but don't want to make it from scratch.

Comment: where should I ask such things then?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio can import data from Excel into Database automatically. Graphs and formulas are a different thing... SSMS comes with Microsoft SQL Server.

Comment: I can add all information to database with no problem. Question would be software that I could use to retrieve various statistics/comparison and so on?